# Re-implement reliable sessions

Tags: .net, wcf

I want to use WCF pipeline to handle requests of some custom format (not XML/SOAP), so I have to reimplement some standard stuff. Also, I need to support sessions.

I had not problem with message encoders and formatters, but I have a problem with sessions:

y service contract is marked with attribute

```
[ServiceContract(
    SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
```

Implementation is marked with attribute

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
```

I have subclass of BindingElement cass, which overrides CanBuildChannelListener and BuildChannelListener methods. Latter returns implementation of IReplySessionChannel.

Everything seems to work, methods are called, objects are created, but there is just one session for all clients. There is just one session, even when I try to access my service from different PCs.

So the question is, how to re-implement reliable sessions properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself. Correct IReplySessionChannel implementation is quite complex. Hints may be found at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751405.aspx
(HttpCookieSession Windows Communication Foundation Sample)